# Формат даты c таймзоной Java

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, simpledateformat

есть `Timestamp` и формат вывода даты `"EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a zzz"`, но как вывести эту дату правильной (тоесть ту что в timestamp) вместе с таймзоной? Как бы я не делал, или коверкает дату, или неверную таймзону отображает